# Dynamical Allocation & Structs - allocating memory dinamically to a string from a struct

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've got a problem regarding Dynamical Allocation & Structs.
The task: I have a struct of students, which looks like that:

```
typedef struct{
  unsigned id;
  char *lastName;
  float grade;
}students_t;
```

I'm not allowed to pass to lastName a maximum number of characters, it must remain a pointer which size I will increase every time.

My code looks like this:

```
unsigned counter = 0;
students_t* students = NULL;
students_t temp;

char char_current;
unsigned char_counter=0;

while (fscanf(inputFile,"%u",&temp.id) == 1) {

    students = realloc(students,(counter+1) * sizeof(students_t));
    students[counter].id=temp.id;
    printf("%d",students[counter].id);

    students[counter].lastName = NULL;
    while (fscanf(inputFile,"%c",&char_current) != ' ') {
        students[counter].lastName = realloc(students[counter].lastName,(char_counter+1) * sizeof(char));
        students[counter].lastName[char_counter] = char_current;

        char_counter++;
    }

    students[counter].lastName[char_counter] = '\0';

    fscanf(inputFile,"%f",&students[counter].grade);


    counter++;
}
```

My problem is with the `fscanf` from the `while` (because the program enters an infinite loop), but I don't know how to actually fix it.

I would be grateful if someone could help me figure it out.
Thank you!

Comment: Check your documentation on what the value returned by `fscanf` means.

Comment: Re "*My problem is with*", What problem? You forgot to specify what problem you are having!

Comment: “The problem” is explained in the last part of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. The while() loop isn't terminating (your initial question).
2. fscanf() is unsafe - there are better alternatives.
3. You're using fscanf() incorrectly.
4. Reading a string a character at a time is inefficient.
5. Repeatedly calling "realloc()"  is inefficient - there are better alternatives.

Here is some example code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING 80

typedef struct {
   unsigned id;
   char *lastName;
   float grade;
} students_t;

students_t* enter_new_student (FILE *inputFile)
{
   char buffer[MAX_STRING];
   unsigned id;
   int iret;

   // Check for end of input
   iret = fscanf(inputFile, "%u", &id);
   if ((iret < 1) || feof(inputFile)) {  // iret should be "1" if successful
      return NULL;
   }

   // Allocate a record and read its data
   students_t *student = (students_t *)malloc(sizeof(students_t));
   iret = fscanf(inputFile, "%s %f", buffer, &student->grade); // iret should be "2" if successful
   student->id = id;
   student->lastName = strdup(buffer);   // strdup() does an implicit "malloc()" and "strcpy()"

   // Return new student
   return student;
}

int main()
{
   students_t *student = NULL;
   int record_counter = 0;
   FILE *fp;

   // Open file
   if (!(fp = fopen("tmp.txt", "r"))) {
      perror("unable to open file");
      return 1;
   }

   // Read student records
   while ((student = enter_new_student(fp))) {
      if (student) {
         ++record_counter;
         printf("new student=%s,id=%u, grade=%f, record_counter=%d\n",
            student->lastName, student->id, student->grade, record_counter);
      }
   }

   // Done
   printf("Done: final record count=%d\n", record_counter);
   return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample "tmp.txt" file:

```
1 Johnson 4.0
2 Jackson 3.5
3 Jamison 3.85
```

And corresponding sample output:

```
new student=Johnson,id=1, grade=4.000000, record_counter=1
new student=Jackson,id=2, grade=3.500000, record_counter=2
new student=Jamison,id=3, grade=3.850000, record_counter=3
```

In general, prefer using [fgets()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) over fscanf(): [Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf)

Notice that I put everything having to do with reading a student record inside a separate function: `enter_new_student()`.  You'll also notice that the "control structure" - the "while loop" is *OUTSIDE* of the function.

There are two (related) conditions that can cause the loop to exit:

1. Didn't read "id"
2. End of file

The reason your original "while loop" failed was that `fscanf()` will never return `' '` ... so you inadvertently coded an "infinite loop".  Here's why:

> https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf
>
> *Return Value*
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided
>   for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either
>   the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is
>   also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error
>   indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set
>   indicate the error.

Comment: Hello @FoggyDay , about the fscanf - this is what they want us to use. And I know that realloc() repeatedly is inefficent in terms of time, but this is what they want us to use. (Probably to see that we are capable of doing it or I don't know).